# Cordova adding platform: Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-whitelist' CordovaError: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater

Tags: cordova

```
cordova platform add android

Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Android project created with cordova-android@6.0.0
Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for android
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Proxymis\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-whitelist':CordovaError: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater
    at C:\Users\Proxymis\Desktop\sendSMS\platforms\android\cordova\lib\check_reqs.js:278:19
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\Proxymis\Desktop\sendSMS\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\Proxymis\Desktop\sendSMS\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\Proxymis\Desktop\sendSMS\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
    at C:\Users\Proxymis\Desktop\sendSMS\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:604:44
    at runSingle (C:\Users\Proxymis\Desktop\sendSMS\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
    at flush (C:\Users\Proxymis\Desktop\sendSMS\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (node.js:370:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:401:11)
Error: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater
```

I think my environnement is OK:

```
JAVA_HOME
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121

java -version
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

Comment: `JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121` it is picking your jre not jdk..what does `echo %JAVA_HOME%` say?

Comment: Does my answer resolve your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set your **`JAVA_HOME`** environment variable to the JDK root folder instead of JRE folder as shown below.

After correcting your JAVA_HOME, do a

```
cordova requirements android
```

to verify you have met the environment requirements for cordova android platform.

[image]